# Open a R script inside another R script [Tableau case]

Tags: r, scripting, tableau-api

Just a question... supposing I have the following R file, called script.R:

```
calculation1 <- function(){
           # multiple calculations goes here.
    }
calculation2 <- function(){
           # multiple calculations goes here.
    }
```

And I want to open this file on another file in order to use **calculation1** and **calculation2** multiple times in different cases.

Is that possible? I mean, something like the following.

```
calculation_script <- Some way, function or method that instantiate script.R in this variable.
calculation_script.calculation1()
calculation_script.calculation2()
```

I need to do this because I need to open script.R file in a Tableau Calculated field.

Comment: Will `source("script.R")` work? With the correct path, that is. Functions would still have original names - `calculation1` and `calculation2`.